# requestAnimationFrame() not refreshing

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm learning how to use requestAnimationFrame() and the animation changes when refreshing the page. Shouldn't it should continuously change the font size without having to refresh it?

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));

function draw(){
  for (i=0; i < 100; i++){
    $("#lw").css("font-size", x);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Comment: Why are you changing font size this way?  Why not use CSS transitions or animations?  Maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: Your loop sets the same value every iteration... You never modify `x`.

Comment: It's just a test to learn how requestAnimationFrame works.

Comment: thank you@AndréDion, declaring x inside the loop fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`requestAnimationFrame` is working like it's supposed to. You're never changing the conditions between calls or loop iterations.

```js
function draw(){
  for (var i = 0, x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)); i < x; i++){
    $("#lw").css("font-size", i);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="lw">Test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop is setting the css to the value of x. Which is set outside of the loop.  If you want the size to get bigger set the font size to i instead of x